# Making a note using LaTeX and finding the formatting of a specific book

Tags: formatting, document-classes, overleaf, books, documentclass-writing

I really want to make my own notes in a friendly format, obviously using LaTeX. But, since I have a little knowledge about LaTeX and its functions, I go through some books, articles, online notes written in LaTeX. But, I really liked [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NR88DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=ashok+das+books+quantum+mechanics&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ashok%20das%20books%20quantum%20mechanics&f=false) book's formatting and style. [Another one](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=oupB7VUGzGcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ashok+das+books+quantum+mechanics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz6tXO0YDyAhWP6XMBHaVlD-wQ6AEwBXoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) from same author Ashok Das and LaTeX typists Judy Mack and Dr. Alex Constandache.

I want to know the documentclass type, formatting, styles, et cetera and et cetera used in this book. I don't know if this kind of question could be asked or not. But I could not resist myself. So, Could anybody write me some code to create a document like these?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the publisher's style files.
[Book Style Files](https://www.worldscientific.com/page/authors/book-stylefiles)

Answer (score 0):

Cover, copyright page etc. are probably done outside Latex and later just combined as pdf.

Starting with the table of content the rest appears to be close to standard. i.e. using `\documentclass{book}` or `\documentclass{scrbook}` (Koma-scripts) will bring you very close to it.

Having an underlining rule in the header can certainly be done with these two classes. If you need more, have a look here: https://ctan.org/search?phrase=book .

Fonts used in those two books you can look up via the pdf's document properties. However, Latex has some built-in rules when to use which one.

Code follows in a minute, or two ;-) // Here it is:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition} % for ch. 2

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Review of classical mechanics}
    In this lecture \ldots we will use in study of quantum mechanics.
    \section{Newton's equation}
    Let us consider a particle \ldots
    \[
    V(x) = - \int_0^x dx' F(x')
    \]
    This is a second order \ldots
    \section{Lagrangian approach}
    Another way to look at it \ldots
    \[
    L = T - V \equiv L(x,\dot x)
    \]
    % --- next one -----------------------
    \chapter{Review of essential mathematics}
    In the following few lectures \ldots
    \section{Linear vector spaces}
    \begin{Defi}
    A set of quatities \{$V_i$\}, with a \ldots
    \end{Defi}
    We are using \ldots
\end{document}
```

Result as pdf-screenshots:

[image: TOC]

[image: Ch. 1]

[image: Ch. 2]

For a start it may be good to stay with the Latex defaults, which will take some time to conquer. Perhaps it's a good idea to start with an introductory book, which is simple enough. "The Latex companion" may be a good add-on; I think the second edition is also the last, from 2007. Since then there have been lots of extensions and improvements coming in various packages via CTAN.

Success :)

P.S.: See also here: https://ctan.org/topic/book-pub

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, publishers have guidelines for publishing. This is also the case with the publisher you mentioned. Sometimes it is enough to search for **Guidelines for Submission** or **Guidelines for Authors** on the corresponding page. For the publisher you are looking for, you will find an immense amount of relevant information here;

[Guidelines for Submission and Style Files](https://www.worldscientific.com/page/authors/journal-stylefiles)

They have a seperate page **General Instructions For Authors (Books)** with direkt link to latex2e files;

[Book Style Files](https://www.worldscientific.com/page/authors/book-stylefiles)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `memoir` class (warning I was the originator) which provides, I think, all the facilities you are after (except perhaps for the cover but with some work this could be accomodated). Have a look at the first 40 odd pages (`> texdoc memoir`) of the manual to see things like a copyright page and contents lists.

Answer (score 0):

I come back to your beginner status. Here are a few sources, that may give you a quick start:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes

Similar: http://www.docs.is.ed.ac.uk/skills/documents/3722/3722-2014.pdf

AND, available as pdf or ebook: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

I suggest getting a quick overview, download and run your Latex tool (if that's still necessary to do, start trying and looking things up as they come your way. The learning curve is less steep than it may appear to be at first glance ;-) ... as long as you don't want to become an export in the zillions of packages within a week or so ...