# Finding font/fontstyle used in a book

Tags: fonts

This question is connected to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606480/making-a-note-using-latex-and-finding-the-formatting-of-a-specific-book) question of mine. The font used in those books is very similar to the default serif font of latex, that is using `utf8` encoding characters. Below I am showing you an image of a word in the book,

> [image]

And using the default, I got this,

> [image]

So, what should I do to get the former font?

Comment: `utf8` is not a font, but an `encoding`.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Bernard. Can you edit the question please?

Comment: Try the package `mlmodern`, see [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596861](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596861/110998).

Comment: I've modified your post, but I'm not sure it's correct: I supposed you didn't specify any particular font, i.e.  you were using the default. If it's not correct, you can edit your post to make it right.

Comment: "Using the default" you got something, but you haven't shown any code so I can only guess: I'd say it's the same font in both pictures. The second one uses probably `\huge`, and you played with the magnification such that the two pictures are the same size. The `\huge` font looks then lighter, as it is supposed to do. But again, no code...

Comment: @campa You can check it yourself, see the fonts in the book through the links and compare it with the default one.

Comment: If you have the book you can get the exact list of fonts used from the pdf reader font menu

Comment: @David Carlise I have tried many ways, but I did not get the result, may be I could get the font, then, what to write in code in latex(and that also did not helped)? And font may not support LaTeX, and there is many questions...

Comment: if you use lualatex or xelatex you can use any system font, so if you showed the fonts used someome could help

Comment: @David Carlisle I dont know if this is what I should do or not. I uploaded the image in font squirrel and got [this](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator?token=1291urvt72qgh2xz).

Comment: no that is just guessing. If you have bought the book and have the pdf you can get the exact font list from the pdf using say pdffonts utility or the acrobat reader fonts menu

Comment: @David Carlisle sorry sir I was unable to do. But, I want to use the font 'symbola' detected by the font squirrel. I even downloaded and uploaded the ttf file, I don't know what to do further. How can I use that font throughout the document?

Comment: I still believe that the book uses just standard Computer Modern fonts. Probably a KoMa class, given the sans-serif section titles. I precisely get your pictures by looking at `\normalsize` at 750% magnification, and at `\huge` at 400%. Larger fonts in CM are lighter by construction.

Comment: as campa says it is probably computer modern (or latin modern) that the book is using but if you want symbola use lualatex and `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{symbola}` is all you need

Comment: @campa could you show the probable font you got, and write some code in answer?

Comment: What is the name of the book, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano Go through the link in the question

Comment: @DlIfE I have seen the pdf. All the fonts are CM and Sans Serif font.